# Compiler tries to use copy constructor even though I'm moving

Tags: c++

I'm trying to move things in and out from my thead safe deque:

```
template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeDeque
{
//..
    T pop_front(void) noexcept
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{_mutex};

        while (_collection.empty())
        {
            _condNewData.wait(lock);
        }
        auto elem = std::move(_collection.front());
        _collection.pop_front();
        return elem;
    }
private:
    std::deque<T> _collection;            // Concrete, not thread safe, storage.
    //...
}
```

I created this class to insert into the Deque:

```
class DecodedFrame
{
public:
    DecodedFrame(){}
    DecodedFrame(const DecodedFrame &decodedFrame) = delete;
    DecodedFrame &operator=(const DecodedFrame &) = delete;
    std::unique_ptr<AVFrame, AVFrameDeleter> avFrame;
```

Now I'm trying to do

```
std::shared_ptr<ThreadSafeDeque<DecodedFrame>> decodedFramesFifo;
//add some `DecodedFrame`s to decodedFramesFifo
DecodedFrame decodedFrame = std::move(decodedFramesFifo->pop_front());
```

But the compiler complains that I deleted the copy assignment constructor, even though I'm trying to use the move assingment constructor. My guess is that it happens because `pop_front` returns `T`, not `T&`. However, returning references makes no sense becaue the object is supposed to leave the deque forever and therefore the reference to it will die.

How can I move things here?

**ps**: how is it possible for the compiler to copy things when the `DecodedFrame` holds an `unique_ptr`? It can't be copied!

Comment: This class is neither movable or copyable. You are trying to use move constructor but your class does not have one. Also there is no such things as "move assingment constructor", it is either "move constructor" or "move assignment operator".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you declared your copy c'tor and assignment operator. Doesn't matter that the declaration deletes them, it's still a user supplied declaration. That suppresses the implicit declaration of the move operations. Your options are to

1. Default the move operations explicitly.
2. Remove the copy operation declarations, they will still be deleted implicitly on account of the noncopyable member.

Answer (score 4):

The copy-ctor/assign operations are deleted (these are also declarations) but that does not implicitly declare/define move-ctor/assign operations.

See p30 of https://fr.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014

You have to declare (default) them.

```
DecodedFrame(DecodedFrame &&) = default;
DecodedFrame &operator=(DecodedFrame &&) = default;
```

In order to avoid such frustrating behaviour, you should consider the *rule of five*.
(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five)

Answer (score 2):

You dont get the move constructor and move assignment operator because your copy constructor and copy assignment operator are user delcared/defined (you deleted them). you can force the default move constructor and move assignment via "=default" (like you did with delete).

But because the class has a unique pointer as member which itself is only move constructible and move assignable, you will get the deletion of the copy constructor and copy assignment for free. just remove you delete statements and you will be fine, since you then again get the move operations.